# How to iterate through only certain type of files using QDirIterator

Tags: c++, qt

I want to iterate through only .xml files (all files under selected folder and its sub-directories), is that possible with `QDirIterator`?

```
QDirIterator iter( rootDir, QDir::Files | QDir::Dirs | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot);

QString fileName;

while(iter.hasNext() )
{
   qDebug() << iter.next();

   fileName = iter.fileName();

   // now I have to check if fileName is indeed a .xml extension
}
```

As can be seen in code above, if my iterator can jump to .xml files only than I don't have to check for file extension in the loop..is it possible?

Answer (score 11):

One of the [constructors of QDirIterator](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdiriterator.html#QDirIterator-4) allows a nameFilters argument:

```
QDirIterator::QDirIterator ( const QString & path, const QStringList & nameFilters, QDir::Filters filters = QDir::NoFilter, IteratorFlags flags = NoIteratorFlags )
```

> Constructs a QDirIterator that can iterate over path, using
>   nameFilters and filters.

The `nameFilters` argument is not properly documented, but there is a good chance it works like in [QDir::setNameFilters](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#setNameFilters).

```
QDirIterator it(rootdir, QStringList() << "*.xml", QDir::Files, QDirIterator::Subdirectories);
while (it.hasNext()) {
    qDebug() << it.next();
}
```